# NSDictionary assign variable from key in loop

Tags: objective-c, arrays, loops, nsdictionary, nsdata

I've got an NSDictionary loop like this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *readDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plist];
NSDictionary *keys = [readDict objectForKey:data]; //Dictionary
for(NSString *object in keys) {
      NSData *(current object name) = [keys objectForKey:object]; //Dictionary
}

// Can I assign ^ the object name to a new NSData var as it loops?
```

Is it possible to assign a variable name from the object name as it loops?

Comment: It is not clear what do you want to receive. Can you add to question your plist data or screenshot and describe expected result?

Comment: Let's say you have four objects (a,b,c,d) - as it's enumerating through the objects is it possible to assign it like `NSData *a`, `NSData *b`, and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Objective-C is basically C with a few extensions. In your vast knowledge of the C language, have you ever seen a way to create variables at runtime? I haven't. So if I figured out correctly what you want to do, you can't.

And what is "data"? Is it a variable containing a string? The line

```
NSDictionary *keys = [readDict objectForKey:data]; //Dictionary
```

assumes that the dictionary readDict has one key-value pair where the key is equal to the string contained in the variable data, and the value is an NSDictionary. Is that what you wanted?

Next, a for loop running over a dictionary will run over the *keys* in that dictionary. So in

```
for(NSString *object in keys)
```

the name "object" is badly chosen, because it is actually a key.

Usually NSDictionary will either contain keys with know values, and you'd never think of using a for-loop to access them. Or you have a dictionary that can contain any number of unknown keys and you want to process them one after the other. You wouldn't have different variables.